# Hiding columns script returns "Those columns are out of bounds."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a script to hide the empty columns from a sheet. Every column with data have some kind of value on the header. So I am creating an array that encapsules all headers and substracts all empty cells. Then I use hideColumns to hide all the columns next to the last header with a value.

This is the script:

```
function hiding() {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var header = hoja.getRange(1, hoja.getMaxColumns()).getValues();

  for (i in header) {
    if (header[i].length == 0) {
      header.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

  var k = header.length + 1;
    hoja.hideColumns(k, hoja.getMaxColumns());
}
```

I keep getting an error message "Those columns are out of bounds." when I debug the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=es#getRange%28Integer,Integer%29) return only the last column (passing only two arguments returns a "range" with a single cell), so that the array will have a single value header.

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=es#getValues%28%29) return a two-dimensional array of values​​, so to determine the length of the value needed something like:

```js
header[0][i].length
```

According to the documentation [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#hideColumns%28Integer,Integer%29): Hides one or more consecutive columns starting at the given index.

The second parameter of the method [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#hideColumns%28Integer,Integer%29) indicates the number of columns to hide starting from the index specified in the first parameter.

In this case the error is generated because it starts from a certain index and tries to hide most of the available columns, for example, `hoja.getMaxColumns()` returns 20 and trying to execute:

`hoja.hideColumns(k, hoja.getMaxColumns());`

from the index 2 (the value of k), hiding the next 20 columns, which effectively is out of bounds.

Perhaps a code like this can be helpful:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function hideEmptyHeaders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0];
  var columnIndex = 0, numColumns = 0;
  headers.forEach(function(header, index) {
    if (!header) {
      if (!columnIndex)
        columnIndex = index + 1;
      numColumns++;
    } else if (columnIndex > 0) {
      ss.hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns);
      columnIndex = numColumns = 0;
    }
  });
  if (columnIndex > 0) ss.hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns);
}
```